# How can i add microsoftOfficeWebComponents owc To Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a machine in office 2013, I installed microsoft office web Components owc 11.0 , but it does not appear in the list of reference vba

[image]

How can I add it to the list?

Answer (score 2):

It's ok, I found it in 
     C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Components\11

Comment: were you able to use the components in office 2013? I'm having issues upgrading from an excel 2003 sheet to 2013